# Multiple Textures with Mirror Modifier

Tags: texturing, uv, mirror

I would like to use multiple textures to paint both sides of a mirror modifier. The idea is to paint one side of the mirror modifier, and duplicate it with the text flipped.

The problem is that when I apply my mirror modifier, the texture is still mirrored with no indication of where the other half of the texture is getting its data from.

How can I use two different images to texture the object? Is there a better way, such as mirroring the entire object EXCEPT for the text? If so, how would that be done?

[image: Image of the Problem]

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the Mirror Texture Settings by checking U or V, or both

[image]

The texture won't be mirrored, and when you apply the mirror modifier you will be able to see all the parts clearly ( *in the UV editor* )

Comment: I've seen this solution, but i don't think it solves my problem. [This](http://i.imgur.com/BGBgUE9.png) is what happens when I apply that technique.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but when you apply your modifier you will be able to position all the parts in UV easily. By the way I've seen that your normals are inverted. Press Ctrl+N in edit mode while all your mesh is selected

Comment: Aha! So i can cut a seam out of that area and create a mirrored texture ONLY for the text. Perfect - I'll work on incorporating this into a more complete answer thank you!

Comment: Would you mind marking it as an answer then

Comment: In Blender 2.8 although it does it, it doesn't show the mirrored UVs in the UV editors, I need to activate something in 2.8 to show them?